# Jailbreak dev - error creating tweak

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, tweak, logos

I'm trying to create an iphone tweak, but I can not compile the tweak.  It always comes up with this error.
What could be the problem?

**TWEAK.M**

```
%hook SBCallAlertDisplay
- (void)updateLCDWithName:(id)name label:(id)label breakPoint:(unsigned)point
{
    name = @"dasdasdasdasdasds"; 
    %orig;
}
%end
```

**MAKE FILE**

```
include theos/makefiles/common.mk
export GO_EASY_ON_ME=1
TWEAK_NAME = tete
tete_FILES = Tweak.xm
tete_FRAMEWORKS = UIKit
include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/tweak.mk
```

**MAKE**

```
sudo make
Making all for tweak tete...
 Linking tweak tete...
Undefined symbols for architecture armv6:
  "_MSHookMessageEx", referenced from:
      global constructors keyed to Tweak.xm.mmin Tweak.xm.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv6
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [.theos/obj/tete.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [internal-library-all_] Error 2
make: *** [tete.all.tweak.variables] Error 2
```

Comment: The problem is that you're missing the library/source code that defines MSHookMessageEx. You'll have to find which source files/external library defines that and make sure it's part of your build.

Comment: I have no idea. You're pretty much on your own with jailbreak stuff. Read the README and INSTALL instructions very carefully that came with the package you're trying to build. They usually have a section on dependencies that you'll need in order to build.

Comment: If your interested in this question why not support the Area 51 proposal for a [jail-breaking Stack Exchange site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18154/ios-jailbreaking-development?referrer=EuWVi6IpN0_KzzEhC7I-Qw2)

Answer (score 0):

"substrate.h" defines it.  Lib is libsubstrate.dylib. But you don't have to #include the .h or link explicitly with the library. Theos should take care of it when you create a Tweak.